# Font awesome icon color

Tags: css, font-awesome

Is posible to color font awesome icon just around edges and inside to be transparent ?
Like in the photo

[image]

I have this code

```
<i class="icon fa fa-check-circle"></i>

.icon{
    color: #26b2ad;
}
```

And it looks :

[image]

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: I tried with border but not worked

Comment: try `color`.... (and post your code here, that's what it's all about)

Comment: share you code to fix it..?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there has been made no effort to solve this issue on it's own.

Comment: Why , just only you don't know the answer of the question that I posted??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by using the "Open"  version of it:

```css
body{
    background: darkblue;
    color: darkblue;
}
i{
    color: #26b2ad;
    font-size: 5em !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="icon fa fa-check-circle"></i>
<i class="icon fa fa-check-circle-o"></i>
                         --------^^
```

Comment: awesome, but not all icons have open version, how to deal with it ?

Comment: Pick another icon, or use the border trick as @M. Ferguson posted.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use border-radius to create the circle around the `i` tag:

```css
i {
border-radius:100%;
border:2px solid green;
padding:10px;
background:red;
color:blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<i class="fa fa-check"></i>
```

Hope this helps

#### Update

I"ve updated the code to show you can color any part of this from the border, background and the FontAwesome icon.

Comment: Thank you M.Ferguson, I like your answer but is not working for me. It only shows the outside border !

Comment: I've updated the snippet to show you can color any part of the icon that you would need. I've done them as three separate colors so that you can see the difference. Is this what you was after?